# How to display image which when opened on browser is getting downloaded?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to show images on an angular application. Problem is that when I am directly opening the image link, it's getting downloaded instead of showing it on the browser. How to grab that image and show it?

The image can be in any format like jpg, jpeg, BMP, png etc

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 0):

use that link in src attribute of img tag

```
<img src="<link>">
```